# "Unknown props" warning on console when attaching additional props

Tags: styled-components

I'm using Styled Components v2.1.1.
The documentation says that to avoid unnecessary wrappers we can use the `.attrs` constructor. See: https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#attaching-additional-props

I've tried to use it but I always receive the following warning in the console:

```
Warning: Unknown props `margin`, `padding` on <input> tag. Remove these props from the element. For details, see (removed )
 in input (created by styled.input)
in styled.input (created by InputContainer)
in div (created by InputContainer)
in InputContainer
```

I've created a Webpack Bin to show the error: https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KpKbVG-Ed0jysHeFVVY

Am I using it in the wrong way or is there an issue?

Answer (score 0):

As it seems, the example provided on the styled components website is not an actual usable example.

Since the attrs function creates attributes for the properties you set, the error is correct in saying that the html `<input>` tag does not support the attributes margin and padding: [MDN - HTML input attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#Attributes)

The error you're seeing was marked as an issue on the [styled-components GitHub](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/1115).
The actual solution is not to literally use the example given in the styled-components documentation. For the full explanation, please refer to the issue report.

The code example given by one of the contributers on Github is to modify the example as follows:

```
const getSize = p => p.size || '1em'

const Input = styled.input.attrs({
    // we can define static props
    type: 'password'
})`
    color: palevioletred;
    font-size: 1em;
    border: 2px solid palevioletred;
    border-radius: 3px;

    /* here we use the dynamically computed props */
    margin: ${getSize};
    padding: ${getSize};
`;
```